# NLP reverse tokenizing (going from tokens to nicely formatted sentence)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Python's Spacy package has a statistical tokenizer that intelligently splits a sentence into tokens. My question is, is there a package that allows me to go backwards, i.e. from list of tokens to a nicely formatted sentence? Essentially, I want a function that lets me do the following:

```
>>> toks = ['hello', ',', 'i', 'ca', "n't", 'feel', 'my', 'feet', '!']
>>> some_function(toks)
"Hello, I can't feel my feet!"
```

It probably needs some sort of statistical/rules-based procedure to know how spacing, capitalization or contractions should work in a proper sentence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Within spaCy you can always reconstruct the original string using `''.join(token.text_with_ws for token in doc)`. If all you have is a list of strings, there's not really a good deterministic solution. You could train a reverse model or use some approximate rules. I don't know a good general purpose implementation of this `detokenize()` function.

Comment: I do have access to the spaCy `token` object. I'll create a dict that matches the list of tokens to formatted sentence. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `nltk` to some extent for detokenization like this. You'll need to do some post processing or modify the regexes, but here is a sample idea:

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer as Detok
detokenizer = Detok()
text = detokenizer.detokenize(tokens)
text = re.sub('\s*,\s*', ', ', text)
text = re.sub('\s*\.\s*', '. ', text)
text = re.sub('\s*\?\s*', '? ', text)
```

There are more edge cases with punctuations, but this is pretty simple and slightly better than `' '.join`

Comment: Thanks, this was the best answer. The only reason that other answer got accepted was because the OP used SpaCy, but many don't. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've described my approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618856/6730526).

And it does create a nice sentence out of tokenized words even if you dont have spacy doc content.